# vue v-for performance issue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to increase the performances of my vuejs template that loops through a list filtered by a custom method `myfiltermethod` and create a component `customcomp` for each item:

```
<customcomp v-for="x in mylist.filter(y => myfiltermethod(y, otherparam))" :data="x"/>
```

The filtering function takes some other parameters that may filter-in or out items depending on the app state.
My issue is that if an item is filtered out and in again it will be created and mounted from scratch even if it has not changed at all. How do I avoid that?

I have tried tweaking the code above:

```
<customcomp v-for="x in mylist.filter(y => y.hasbeenshown || myfiltermethod(y, otherparam))" v-show="myfiltermethod(y, otherparam)" :data="x"/>
```

Where `hasbeenshown` is set to true the first time an item is shown. This indeed avoids the components to be re-created everytime but I have not been able to measure any performance gains...

Comment: The reason is that you create `<customcomp>` every time.
If the contents of `<customcomp>` are fixed, you should create all `<customcomp>` without filtering `mylist`.
Then use `v-show` to hide only what you don't want to see.
For your second code, isn't it enough to use `v-show` and not `mylist.filter()`?

Comment: @kako-jun mylist may contain many items of which only a few may ever be filtered in, so only using v-show will create most of them for nothing

Comment: I see. Not only the drawing speed but also the size of HTML is important. I have no idea, sorry.